# Nginx rewrite: check file access if not image

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have some problems with rewriting rules apache to nginx.
In .httaccess it was:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(images/.*\.[a-zA-Z]{3,4})$ /getFile?file=$1 [NC]
```

And my nginx rewrite that doesn't work:

```
location /images/(.*) {
    if ( $uri !~ ^/\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)$ ) {
        rewrite ^(images/(.*)\.([a-zA-Z]))$ /getFile?file=$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for your information: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple conditions for nginx like:

```
if ($uri ~* "^/images/.*"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($uri !~* "^/images/.*\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)$"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(images/.*\.[a-zA-Z]{3,4})$ /getFile?file=$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*) {
    if ($request_filename ~* ^.+.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp)$) {
        break;
    }
    rewrite ^/(images.*)$ /getFile?file=$1;
}
```